# How To set a view bottom line's centre to main View's centre point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

How can I set this type of arrangement as shown in figere.
I have two view.View 1 is main Parent view.And view 2 is child view.
How can I set Child's bottom line's centre point with my Parent view's centre point.

## Image

[image]

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
view2.center = CGPointMake(view1.frame.size.width / 2.0, view1.frame.size.height / 2.0 - view2.frame.size.height / 2.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Drag view2 inside view1 then set view2 to horizontally centered inside view1 using "**center horizontally in container**" constraint. Then set "**bottom space to container**" constraint between view2 and view1. After that select "**bottom space to container**" constraint Click on **Attribute inspector** there is a drop down value for field name **First Item** click on that drop down and select "**center Y**". And set constant to 0. You should get what u r looking for.

Comment: alternatively, you can set the `multiplier` value in the attribute inspector to 0.5 to do the same thing.  The advantage is that you can use this to position something at **any** percentage position in a view